# Can't get the new 2009 XAML primitives working, why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

What I'd like to use:  [2009 XAML primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002(VS.100).aspx#xaml_2009_language_primitives)

How it would be nice to use them:

```
<sapv:ExpressionTextBox xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ExpressionType="x:String"  />
```

What actually happens:

> "Type reference cannot find the public type named String"

The examples I see don't have updated namespaces.  I tried 2009 and 2010, but to no avail.  This is in VS 2010 RTM.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the namespace seems to be wrong

Comment: @cody sigh.  "The examples I see don't have updated namespaces. I tried 2009 and 2010, but to no avail."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the key sentence on the documentation page is this:

> In WPF, you can use XAML 2009 features but only for XAML that is not markup-compiled. Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and features.

So, if you're writing loose XAML that's loaded at runtime via a `XamlReader`, you can use these primitives.  If you're writing XAML that's compiled, you can't.

Comment: Wow, that's awful.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems that 6 years later this is still the case :(

Comment: So how can I use 2009 xaml in VS2017?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

to import clr namespaces.
Then use for example `clr:String` to reference a specific type.

Comment: Sigh.  "What I'd like to use: 2009 XAML primitives".  Yes, I know how to do this in the old crappy way.  Well, I'm in the land of unicorns and magic puppies known as 4.0.  Gone is the bad old days of importing mscorlib to access primitive types in xaml.  You understand what I asked about now?

Comment: I was trying to help you. Why so arrogant?

Comment: @codymanix It's sad, but programming can turn us badly arrogant sometimes. Mainly when things don't work as expected(2013 and no support for an amazing 2009 feature, in other words, I still can't using this s***). I think that Will was just releasing its angry on XAML, not on you haha