# Can WPF ObjectDataProvider invoke generic method?

Tags: wpf, generics, objectdataprovider

Commonly known, `ObjectDataProvider` can invoke simple nongeneric methods like that

XAML:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SimpleKey" MethodName="Nongeneric" ObjectType="{x:Type local:SomeClass}">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public static SomeClass
{
    public static void NongenericMethod()
    {
        // method body        
    }

    public static void GenericMethod<T>()
    {
        // method body
    }
}
```

Is it possible that `ObjectDataProvider` invokes generic method? Something like that:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SimpleKey" MethodName="GenericMethod<local:OtherClass>" ObjectType="{x:Type local:SomeClass}">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Comment: Generics are not supported in XAML. You can check out workaround for it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152196/how-use-listt-within-xaml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how use List<T> within xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152196/how-use-listt-within-xaml)