# Create a generic list in xaml 4.5+

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, .net-4.5

I am trying to make a rule list for one of my usercontrols. List contains a custom type `List<StringInputRule>`. I am using `DependancyProperty` to databind.

I am trying to set the rules in xaml for the control as such:

```
<controlsDefault:DateEditWithStringInput>
    <controlsDefault:DateEditWithStringInput.Rules>
       <x:Array Type="controlsDefault:StringInputRule" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <controlsDefault:StringInputRule Key="T" Amount="1" Unit="Day"/>
            <controlsDefault:StringInputRule Key="W" Amount="1" Unit="Week"/>
            <controlsDefault:StringInputRule Key="M" Amount="1" Unit="Month"/>
       </x:Array>
     </controlsDefault:DateEditWithStringInput.Rules>
</controlsDefault:DateEditWithStringInput>
```

c# code for dependancy property for the control:

```
public partial class DateEditWithStringInput : UserControl
{
    public DateEditWithStringInput()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rules = new List<StringInputRule>();
    }

    public IList<StringInputRule> Rules
    {
        get { return (IList<StringInputRule>)GetValue(RulesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RulesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RulesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rules", typeof(IList<StringInputRule>), typeof(DateEditWithStringInput), new PropertyMetadata(new List<StringInputRule>()));
}
```

So the following approach does not pass any values, yet it compiles. I have read that generic types could be initialized within xaml from 2009 version with 4.0, yet I could have not located an example.

**My question:** How to define generic List in xaml?

**Edit:** As to this day there is no solid solution to the problem.

**WorkAround** (as pointed by Szabolcs Dézsi): [how use List<T> within xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152196/how-use-listt-within-xaml/7152297#7152297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
<controlsDefault:DateEditWithStringInput.Rules>
    <generic:List x:TypeArguments="controlsDefault:StringInputRule">
        <controlsDefault:StringInputRule Key="T" Amount="1" Unit="Day"/>
        <controlsDefault:StringInputRule Key="W" Amount="1" Unit="Week"/>
        <controlsDefault:StringInputRule Key="M" Amount="1" Unit="Month"/>
    </generic:List>
</controlsDefault:DateEditWithStringInput.Rules>
```

[`x:TypeArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476(v=vs.110).aspx) is a XAML 2009 feature. Unfortunately it's not supported in compiled XAML, so you won't be able to use it in your WPF application. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414862/can-xaml-2009-related-markup-extensions-be-used-in-wpf), [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/10/23/103-xaml-2009/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792007(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot mark this as an answer since it just states the fact that you cannot do it, yet I have actually already solved it by adding additional non generic type which inherits from List<StringInputRule> and use child class as  type. You can alter your answer accordingly and I will mark it as an answer. Have a good day!

Comment: Yes, I know about that, the question is a duplicate anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7152297/4620101  although I feel this is a workaround and not an answer for  your specific question: "How to define generic List in xaml?"

Comment: Initially I was looking for a more solid way to do it as you mentioned in the comment, that is why I written this questions. Apparently, you cannot do without that workaround :) Thanks for the effort!